# get multiple values from same JOIN in MySQL and Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, join

This is a follow on from another question that was partially answered and I need to take it a step further.

I have a database that has tables for Team and Fixture. The relationship between these tables is Many to Many which creates a JOIN table called team has fixture.

```
team

team_id
team_name
team_logo

fixture 

fixture_id
fixture_text
fixture_comp
fixture_type
fixture_level
fixture_date
```

The relationship between these two tables is many to many which creates a JOIN table called team_has_fixture which has a composite PK made up from team_id and fixture_id

```
team_has_fixture

team_team_id
fixture_fixture_id
team_team_id2      //added this column to hold the id for second the team in the fixture
```

I am trying to create a fixture that uses all the data from the fixture table and the team logo for the two teams involved in the fixture from the team table.

e.g layout of fixture will look like this - team 1 logo - fixture details - team 2 logo

I have currently got it to this stage - without the logo for team 2

e.g layout of fixture will look like this - team 1 logo - fixture details -

What I am trying to do is get the logo for the second team to display as well.

This is the code that I currently have.

MODEL

```
 <?php  
 class Fixture_model extends CI_Model {  


public function __construct()
{
  parent::__construct();

}
function fixtures() 

    {
        //$fixture_level = "Roinn 1B";
        //Query the fixture table for every record and row  

        $results = array();

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('team_has_fixture');

        $this->db->join('team', 'team_has_fixture.team_team_id = team.team_id');

         // I tried the line below to get the second logo out 
            but it just overrides the line above and displays the second logo
            instead of the first one but not both 

        //$this->db->join('team as t', 'team_has_fixture.team_team_id2 = t.team_id');
        $this->db->join('fixture', 'team_has_fixture.fixture_fixture_id = fixture.fixture_id');


        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows() > 0) 
        {
         $results = $query->result();
        }

        return $results;   

    }
```

I have the following code in my view to display the retrieved results from the database

VIEW

```
<?php

     if (is_array($results))
     {
       if( !empty($results) ) 
       {

         foreach($results as $row) 
         {

          echo '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">';
          echo '<div class="thumbnail">';
          echo '<tr>';
          echo '<h4>';
          echo '<td>'.'<img src="'."$row->team_logo".'"> '.$row->fixture_text.'</td>'."</br></br>";
          echo '<td>'.$row->fixture_level.'</td>'."</br></br>";
          echo '<td>'.$row->fixture_comp.'</td>'."</br>";
          echo '</h4>';

          echo '<td>'.$row->fixture_date.'</td>'."</br></br>";
          echo '</tr>';
          echo '</div>';
          echo '</div>';
         }
       }

      else echo "Not Array";
    }

    ?>
```

This all works except I need to get the second team logo as well - Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Try this! :-)

```
$this->db->join('team', 'team_has_fixture.team_team_id = team.team_id AND team_has_fixture.team_team_id2 = t.team_id');
```

Comment: I currently have this which displays the second team logo - it is overwriting the first one `$this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('team_has_fixture as tf');
            
            $this->db->join('team as t1', 'tf.team_team_id = t1.team_id');
            $this->db->join('team as t2', 'tf.team_team_id2 = t2.team_id');
            $this->db->join('fixture', 'tf.fixture_fixture_id = fixture.fixture_id');` trying to figure out how to access it in the VIEW

Comment: Did you try my solution? Could you use UNION with a WHERE clause, instead of joins?

Comment: I tried your solution it returned an error on t.team_id not being declared. i.e team as t should be used somewhere